# Excel handling in jmeter to add multiple dynamic rows

Tags: excel, dynamic, jmeter, apache-poi

I need to create an excel file for upload scenario in jmeter. The excel has 3 columns and number of rows is a dynamic value coming from parameter file.
The row values cannot have same data for different excel. So I am using random string to create data. By hard coding number of rows I am able to create file with below code using apache poi but facing issues to handle dynamic number of rows. Can somebody please provide solution?

Below is the code which is working fine for creating 5 rows.

```
def path = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir;
def separator = File.separator;
def sourceFileName = "CreateDynamicExcel";

HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Billing");

Object[] dataTypes = [
["Column1Header","Column2Header","Column3Header"],
["${__RandomString(10,abcdefghij,)}","${__Random(100000000,199999999,)}","${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrst,)}"],
["${__RandomString(10,abcdefghij,)}","${__Random(100000000,199999999,)}","${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrst,)}"],
["${__RandomString(10,abcdefghij,)}","${__Random(100000000,199999999,)}","${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrst,)}"],
["${__RandomString(10,abcdefghij,)}","${__Random(100000000,199999999,)}","${__RandomString(10,abcdefghijklmnopqrst,)}"]];


int rowNum = 0;

for (Object[] datatype:datatypes)

HSSFRow = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
int colNum = 0;
for(Object filed:datatype){
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(colNumn+=);
if(filed.instanceof(String){
cell.setCellValue((String) filed);
}
if(filed.instanceof(Integer){
cell.setCellValue((Integer) filed);
}
}

try{

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path+separator+sourceFileName+".xls"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
e.printStacktrace();
}
```

Comment: @dmitri could you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be inlining [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in Groovy scripts because:

1. It conflicts with Groovy [GString Template Engine syntax](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html)
2. [Only first occurrence will be cached and used for subsequent iterations](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

So you can use the following expressions instead:

- `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10)`
- `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(100000000, 199999999)`
- etc.

In case of any problems - take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), in case of any issues you should find the root cause or at least a clue there

Comment: The code is working fine if I copy paste the random string function desired number of times. What I want to achieve is instead of copy paste I want to use loop to create data for number of rows dynamically as the expected upload size of rows is around random number 1K. I am new to groovy and not able to come up with solution.