# Webdriver Sampler is not working in Windows10

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, windows-10, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-4.0

I am trying to set up the webdriver sampler in Jmeter for Chrome. I have downloaded the chromedriver as per my chrome version and specified the path in Chromedriver config. While executing test I am getting Browser has not been configured. Please ensure at least one webDriverConfig is created message.

chrome version: 86.0.4240.183
Jmeter Version: 4.0
Jmeter Plugin Version: 1.3
Selenium version in jmeter lib: 3.14

Please let me know if anything missing and how can we resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot say "if anything missing" without seeing:

1. The folder where you have unpacked `chromedriver.exe`
2. [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) setup
3. The contents of [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Here is the evidence that ChromeDriver works fine with the WebDriver Sampler on Windows 10

[image]

So the only piece of advice I can give you so far is considering upgrading to [latest JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) as you should be using it according to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

Comment: Thank you DMitri. It worked after upgrading to Jmeter 5.1

Comment: Also could you please help me with the solution for following Question? I am not sure if it is allowed to post the link here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66520998/excel-handling-in-jmeter-to-add-multiple-dynamic-rows

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved after upgrading Jmeter version to 5.1.1.